# Start script on scroll and max width

Tags: javascript, html, css, responsive-design, scroll

I've got this:

JavaScript:

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
if  ($(window).scrollTop() >= 100){
     $('#normal_menu').css({height: '50px'});
} else {
     $('#normal_menu').css({height: '120px'});
    }
});
```

It's working fine. But now I want the code only to work when the screen width is less then 924px. I've found this: `if( $(window).width() < 924)` but how do I implement this in my code?

Comment: Is there problem that you're re-sizing the window during the interaction? (And constantly having to check for the width)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
    if($(window).width() < 924) { // <--- inserted if statement here.
    if ($(window).scrollTop() >= 100) {
        $('#normal_menu').css({
            height: '50px'
        });
    } else {
        $('#normal_menu').css({
            height: '120px'
        });
    }
    } // <--- inserted closing bracket here.
});
```

**P.S:** This will only work if window's `width` is LESS than `924`.... so even if it is `924`, it won't work!

Comment: yep, i will when i can (have to wait 10 min). One more question: what if i want the effect to go smooth?

Comment: You might want to use `animate()`...check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hellosze/MMgXu/) I found.